# accessing a different user's information in django

Tags: django

I know to access the logged-in user's data we use `request.user`. My goal is to list all the users in the table and have a link to their profile page. How do I make the link go to the user's profile page?

I have the following:

```
# app/views.py
def tutors_list(request):
  user_list = CustomUser.objects.all()
  context = {
    'user_list': user_list
  }  
  return render(request, 'tutors_list.html', context)

def show_profile(request, username):
  user = CustomUser.objects.get(username = username) ### NOT DISPLAYING RIGHT USER
  #user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=id)
  context = {
    'user': user
  }  
  return render(request, 'show_profile.html', context)


# myproject/urls.py
url_patterns = [
  # ...
  path('show_profile/', views.show_profile, name='show_profile'),
  # ...
```

I'm getting an error saying `show_profile` is expecting 1 more argument, `username`. How exactly would this model work if I need to pull data for a specific user in the database and not the logged-in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error says  `show_profile` is expecting 1 more argument, `username`, so you need to pass username in your url pattern:

```
 path('<str:username>/show_profile/', views.show_profile, name='show_profile'),
```